# Issue Installing transformers==4.18.0.dev0 from environment.yml File

Tags: python

I created a virtual environment from the environment.yml file, and all packages were installed successfully except for the 'transformers' package. The requirement is to install 'transformers==4.18.0.dev0', but when I run the command:

> `$pip install transformers==4.18.0.dev0`

> `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement transformers==4.18.0.dev0 (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for transformers==4.18.0.dev0`

> `$pip install transformers==4.18.0`

> `ERROR: Package 'urllib3' requires a different Python: 3.7.7 not in '>=3.8'`

I'm hesitant to install transformer==4.18.0 because I'm worried it might not be compatible with other packages when using Python 3.8 or above. Is there a way to install the version that the previous developer used, transformer==4.18.0.dev0?"

Comment: I think, u can install transformers==4.18.0 instead of transformers==4.18.0.dev0

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using the wrong command. To install transformers 4.18.0, you should run `pip install transformers==4.18.0` and this version is compatible with python 3.6-3.9. See
https://pypi.org/project/transformers/4.18.0/